# AudioEmbed vs. AudioPlayer in Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

I am trying to grab audio post, but AudioEmbed never return anything from Soundcloud, AudioPlayer works fine,

So what is the difference between them? Should I use AudioEmbed by way of precaution?

Any ideas??